LTspice and ngspice simulation results differ by 5-6GHz
I simulated a basic CMOS inverter based 3 stage ring oscillator in both LTspice and ngspice, using the same model files (using NCSU's freepdk45 models (VTG slow slow corner)). I expected there to be some difference between the measurements but, I didn't expect around 5-6 GHz worth of difference between the two simulators.
With LTspice, I am getting a frequency of around 26GHz, whereas with ngspice I am getting around 20GHz (a period of around 50ps).Here is a link to the files for both LTspice and Xschem+Ngspice. To the best of my knowledge I have made the schematics and netlists the same in both of them and ran transient simulation for both of them. Yet, the frequency differs by around 6GHz. Another fact to note is,I also tried the simulation with Xyce and that agrees with ngspice, so I am starting to feel like LTspice can't be trusted. Am I right?
Any and all help will be appreciated as to which simulator should I trust, since I am just starting out in year 3 of my 5 year BSEE+ MSEE(in Analog and RF IC design) program, I would like to know which of these free tools can I trust, till I get access to Cadence tools from my university.

You should paste in the content of the model files. (remember to use code format) That share link will be unavailable in a while (if anyone would even be brave enough to click it), and then your question would be context-less.

If you want to compare SPICE engines one-to-one and avoid any user error, you should first build it in LTspice and export the netlist (View->SPICE Netlist) to a text file.  Then you can run that netlist text file in both LTspice directly and the ngspice .exe directly.  You can add a .control section to the end of the netlist for ngspice if needed but it's not necessary.  Adding an additional UI through Xschem just complicates things.

Here is my attempt at what I suggested above.  The results are exactly the same, so there's probably a difference in the way you constructed the circuits.  My method avoids that possibility and just compares the SPICE engines.  One final note, I had to change the tran command in ngspice to .tran 0.1p 0.2n to be compatible.  LTspice uses a modified syntax for .tran.

@SteKulov I just tried running the netlist in ngspice, had to modify it a bit, since some ltspice features are not supported in ngspice, but it does give me the same 26GHz. Though, I still couldn't find the difference between the two netlists

The netlists are not the same, and I think I see the discrepancy.  It's in how you drew the circuit in LTspice.  I'll try to post an answer.

26GHz goes through everything because everything looks like a capacitor at that frequency, you'd probably be better off with a 3D field solver that can handle that frequency if you want to bring this into the real world

If you want to compare SPICE engines one-to-one while avoiding any user error, you should first build it in LTspice and export the netlist (via menu command View->SPICE Netlist) to a text file. Then you can run that netlist text file in both LTspice directly and ngspice directly. You can add a .control section to the end of the netlist for ngspice if needed, but it's not necessary if you're OK with just typing run and plot V(Vosc) manually in ngspice. Adding an additional UI through Xschem just complicates things since you add the possibility that you drew/constructed the circuits differently through both UIs.
Here is my attempt at doing what I suggested above.  Below is my exported netlist.  I had to change the .tran command a bit since LTspice uses a unique syntax for .tran.  You also had erroneous .ic commands I got rid of that LTspice was simply ignoring.
* InverterRingOsc.asc
XX1 Vosc N001 cmos_inverter
XX2 N001 N002 cmos_inverter
XX3 N002 Vosc cmos_inverter
C1 N001 0 0.2f
C2 N002 0 0.2f
C3 Vosc 0 0.2f

* block symbol definitions
.subckt cmos_inverter In Out
M1 Out In 0 N002 CMOSN l={L} w={WN} ad={AsN} as={AsN} pd={PsN} ps={PsN}
M2 Vdd In Out N001 CMOSP l={L} w={WP} ad={AsP} as={AsP} pd={PsP} ps={PsP}
Vdd1 Vdd 0 0.95
.param L=45n WN=135n WP=270n AsN=WN*L AsP=WP*L PsN=WN+2*L PsP=WP+2*L tola=0.05
.ends cmos_inverter

* .dc Vin 0 1.8 0.01
* .ac dec 100 50 10G
.ic V(Vosc)=0
.tran 0.1p 0.2n
.temp 75
.include 45nm_SS.pm
* .param tolb=0.03 tola=0.05
* .step param run 1 100 1
.end

And here is the plot of V(Vosc) between both programs.  They are identical.

This means there is a discrepancy in how you constructed the circuits in each UI.

I believe I found it here in the lines for the MOSFET instances:
LTspice:
M1 Out In 0 N002 CMOSN l={L} w={WN} ad={AsN} as={AsN} pd={PsN} ps={PsN}
M2 Vdd In Out N001 CMOSP l={L} w={WP} ad={AsP} as={AsP} pd={PsP} ps={PsP}

Xschem:
M1 net1 osc GND GND nmos w={WN} l={L} ad={AsN} as={AsN} pd={PsN} ps={PsN} m=1
M2 net1 osc VDD VDD pmos w={WP} l={L} ad={AsP} as={AsP} pd={PsP} ps={PsP} m=1

The body nodes in the LTspice version are floating!  They should be connected to the source nodes, as you were intending.  This happens because of how you used the nmos4 and pmos4 symbols when drawing the circuit in LTspice.
This is how you drew it:

This is how you should draw it:

In your version, the wires hanging off the body pins are dangling and not connected to anything.  It's a bit hard to see since the default color scheme uses light blue for wires and dark blue for symbol drawings.  You're visually mistaking part of the symbol drawing for a wire.  Some people change the default color scheme to prevent these kinds of things from happening.  I can see the color difference, so it doesn't bother me.
You can get a better idea of why this happens by editing the nmos4 symbol.  Those circles surrounded by squares are the actual pins.  You drew a wire from one pin to just a plain old line which does nothing.

TLDR: 
You can trust both simulators, just be a little more mindful of our own proclivity for errors.
